# How can I make this background to see full?

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

[link](http://dg-site.com/bagel/pagina1.html)

Unfortunately as you can see in the picture below, my background is incomplete.
Missing top menu bar.

http://i59.tinypic.com/259vg5f.jpg

This is **code CSS:**

```
body{ 
  background: url(http://dg-site.com/bagel/imagini/rsz_1home.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

}
```

How can I solve this problem?
I tried to make the image smaller and still do not go.
It somehow descends below background?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try use `background-size:contain`

Comment: The question is not well written and it is impossible where the problem is. Please add a jsfiddle and explain better the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **CSS**

```
body{ 
  background: url(http://dg-site.com/bagel/imagini/rsz_1home.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set background-position to top.

You should not be trying to use the menu from an image, if that is what you're attempting to do. It would be lot easier to make your own navigation bar.